# What's wrong with my form action?

Tags: html

I would like my form to send me an email, but I'm not sure where/how to code the html so that all fields in the form populate the email. Or, is this really supposed to go to a page on the server side?

Here's my existing code. Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
 <!-- Contact Section -->
  <div class="section contact" id="contact">
    Contact
    <h2>Say hello</h2>
    <p>Whether you have a communication need to be fully developed, or a quick question for a no-charge opinion or assesment, share the goods here.</p>

    <form action="sendEmail.php" method="POST" class="myForm clearfix" autocomplate="off"> 


      <div class="form-field">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">

      </div>

      <div class="form-field">

        <label for="issue">Describe your issue or opportunity </label>
        <textarea name="issue" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

      </div>

      <div class="form-field">

      <label for="file">Attach a file</label>
      <input type="file" id="file">

      </div>

      <div class="form-field">

      <label for="email">Email</label>
     <!--  <input type="text" id="email"> -->
      <input type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Please enter your email address">

    </div>

    <div class="form-field">

      <label for="phone">Phone </label>
      <input type="text" id="phone">

    </div>

    <div class="form-field">


      I prefer to be contacted by:
      Email <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">
      Phone <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone">

      <!-- <form method="post" action="mailto:info@whatshouldisay.ca" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit form" />  -->

<input type="submit" value="Submit"  -->

    </div>


    </form>


  </div>
```

Comment: "Or, is this really supposed to go to a page on the server side?"  You tell us.  Why did you comment out the "mailto" action and replace it with action="sendEmail.php" if you don't want it to go to the sendEmail.php page on the server?

Comment: @mbeckish I thinking that asking them to fill out a form probably should go to the server side, but I don't know how to set that up. If it's too complicated to explain, I can take out all the form fields and just have them send me an email, but it really doesn't give me what I need to help users out who come to my site. For example, I am hoping they will tell me a little about their project and attach a document etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `mailto:`, which just opens the user's email client with fields prefilled, you don't use a POST form, you use a GET form.

```
<form action="mailto:test@example.com">
    Subject: <input name="subject"><br>
    Body: <input name="body"><br>    
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/gQuZk/)

---

If you want to send the email directly from your server (bypassing the user's email client entirely), you need to [set up a script](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+send+email) to handle the form post.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I think that's what I want to do.